# Creating a dynamic table from a combobox in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am trying to set up a query where a field is searched for on a table, the table I want to select the information from will change each time. I have tables for different years of admission to a club (2011,2012 etc). I want a user to be able to select a year from a combobox on a form and then this dynamically change the table the data is being selected from.

The code I am using makes sense to me, but I am a novice. Access says there is a syntax error. Please help!

Code:

```
SELECT [Admission No#] 
FROM [Forms]![Control Form]![YearSelect];
```

Comment: Can you post the surrounding code where you have put this query?

Answer (score 0):

it would be better to use a filter.

1. Create a form (Continuous Forms or Datasheet) to show search result. You can open it or use as a subform.
2. Implement OnClick event for Search button.

   Dim stFilter as String

   stFilter = "age = " & Me.FLD_AGE

   '-- first way
   DoCmd.OpenForm "SearchResult", , , stFilter

   '-- second way
   With Me.SearchResult.Form '-- SearchResult is the name of SubForm control
     .Filter = stFilter
     .FilterOn = True
   End With